# Why is this creating a multi digit response when I call the figure function?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

When I am calling the figure function below it is barfing out like a thousand digits when I only want 4 separate pairs of 2 digit numbers. I am clearly defining a number in the s variables and am adding them in the figure function. What is going wrong?? For example one of the numbers I would like to have is something like this:

12 34 54 72

But I get this:

13694846 894846 7846 26

```
var s1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8 + 1);
var s2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8 + 1);
var s3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8 + 1);
var s4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8 + 1);
var s5 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8 + 1);
var s6 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8 + 1);
var s7 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8 + 1);
var s8 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8 + 1);

var lives = 3;

var time = 5000;

function figure(a1, a2, a3 ,a4, a5, a6, a7, a8){

var all = a1 + "" + a2 + "" + a3 + "" + a4 + "" + a5 + "" + a6 + "" + a7 + "" + a8;

var als = String(all);

var p1 = als.substring(0);
var p2 = als.substring(1);
var p3 = als.substring(2);
var p4 = als.substring(3);
var p5 = als.substring(4);
var p6 = als.substring(5);
var p7 = als.substring(6);
var p8 = als.substring(7);

var n1 = Number(p1);
var n2 = Number(p2);
var n3 = Number(p3);
var n4 = Number(p4);
var n5 = Number(p5);
var n6 = Number(p6);
var n7 = Number(p7);
var n8 = Number(p8);

var g1 = n1 + n2;    
var g2 = n3 + n4;
var g3 = n5 + n6;
var g4 = n7 + n8;

console.log(g1 + " " + g2 + " " + g3 + " " + g4);


}

figure(s1, s2, s3 ,s4, s5, s6, s7, s8);
```

Comment: Have you read any [doco for `.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)? (And as an aside, why are you creating groups of eight variables? Arrays and loops are your friend.)

Comment: I am still trying to learn Javascript, and W3 Schools said .substring

Comment: @Bubblegumz [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) is often a more reputable source for learning and documentation than w3schools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main problems with your code:

1. You are calling the [`.substring()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) with just a start index, which means it selects a substring from that index through to the end of the string. You need to specify an end index, like `var p1 = als.substring(0,1);`, or if you only want one character just use `.charAt()` instead.
2. You don't need to convert the strings to numbers before adding them, because you seem to want to take `"1"` and `"2"` and get `"12"`, but if you convert them to numbers you get `1 + 2` which is `3`. So just remove that `Number()` stuff.

As an aside, you can replace this:

```
var all = a1 + "" + a2 + "" + a3 + "" + a4 + "" + a5 + "" + a6 + "" + a7 + "" + a8;

var als = String(all);
```

...with this:

```
var als = "" + a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 + a7 + a8;
```

...because if you start with a string any numbers that you add to it will automatically be converted to strings. What you had on those lines will work, but is way more complicated than needed.

In the following collapsed code snippet, I make the above changes to your existing code but leave the rest as is - you can see it working if you expand the snippet and click the "Run" button:

```js
var s1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8 + 1);
var s2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8 + 1);
var s3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8 + 1);
var s4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8 + 1);
var s5 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8 + 1);
var s6 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8 + 1);
var s7 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8 + 1);
var s8 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8 + 1);

var lives = 3;

var time = 5000;

function figure(a1, a2, a3 ,a4, a5, a6, a7, a8){

var als = "" + a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 + a7 + a8;

var p1 = als.charAt(0);
var p2 = als.charAt(1);
var p3 = als.charAt(2);
var p4 = als.charAt(3);
var p5 = als.charAt(4);
var p6 = als.charAt(5);
var p7 = als.charAt(6);
var p8 = als.charAt(7);

var g1 = p1 + p2;    
var g2 = p3 + p4;
var g3 = p5 + p6;
var g4 = p7 + p8;

console.log(g1 + " " + g2 + " " + g3 + " " + g4);

}

figure(s1, s2, s3 ,s4, s5, s6, s7, s8);
```

But you'll notice you have a lot of repetitive code. If you use arrays to hold similar values, and manipulate them via loops, then you don't need to repeat yourself so much. Here's a really simple example of that, to get the same result:

```js
var randomDigits = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  // the array .push()` method adds an item to the end of the array
  randomDigits.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 8 + 1));
}

function figure(digits) {
  var groups = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i += 2) {
    groups.push("" + digits[i] + digits[i + 1]);
  }
  console.log(groups);
  console.log(groups.join(" "));
}

figure(randomDigits);
```

(I would probably make further structural changes if it were my code, but as a starting point I just wanted to show you a simple way to take what you had and convert it to use [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) instead.)

Comment: Thank you! that was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer fix your problems. Nevertheless if you just want to generate 4 2-digit numbers, it is more convenient a solution like this one:

```
var ss = [];
for (var idx = 0; idx < 8; idx ++) {
   var s = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8 + 1)
   ss.push (s);
}

function figure (as) {

   var gs = [];
   for (var idx = 0; idx < as.length; idx+=2)
      if (idx%2===0) gs.push (
        as[idx] * 10 + as[idx + 1]
      );

   return gs;

}

console.log (
  figure f(ss)
);
```